# How to monitor the last row of MySQL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to monitor the last row of a Mysql database and when it is changed I am going to display a message, but I am not sure how to monitor with C #.

I have already been able to request the last row from time to time, but I would like to display it only if it is different from the previous one

this first part starts my counter along with the Load of Form:

```
private void AnteSala_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer
            {
                Interval = 2 * 60 * 1000,
                SynchronizingObject = this
            };
            timer.Elapsed += delegate
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(@"tentou update check 1");
                ReadInformationFromeMessage();
                //MessageBox.Show(@"passou 1");
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
```

this second part takes my last row message from the bank:

```
private void ReadInformationFromeMessage()
        {
            try
            {
                const string mySelectQuery =
                    "select * from send_eMessages order by id desc limit 1";
                var myCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, ConexaoBancoMySql.GetConexao());
                var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var eMessage = (reader.GetString("eMessage"));

                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                   {

                       var pop = new PopupNotifier
                       {
                           //escopo de mensagem
                           TitleText = "*  Informativo de Segurança  *",
                           ContentText = "" + eMessage,
                           //fim do escopo de mensagem
                           TitleFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12),
                           //cor do titulo do form
                           TitleColor = Color.White,
                           BodyColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 75, 0),
                           //contorno do form
                           BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0),
                           //cor da fonte do aviso
                           ContentColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255),
                           //tamanho da fonte
                           ContentFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12F),
                           //cor da fonte do aviso quando mouse em cima
                           ContentHoverColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255),
                           //centralizacao da mensagem no form 
                           ImagePadding = new Padding(0),
                           ContentPadding = new Padding(10),
                           Delay = 15000,
                           GradientPower = 150,
                           //tamanho da borda superior
                           HeaderHeight = 1,
                           Scroll = true,
                           ShowCloseButton = true,
                           ShowGrip = true,
                           ShowOptionsButton = false,

                       };
                        pop.Popup();
                   });
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                ConexaoBancoMySql.FecharConexao();
            }
       }
```

Comment: Rows and row order in a  DB are not defined, so what does 'monitor the last row' mean?  Are you simply trying to determine when new data has been added to a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `id` changes each time a new message is added to the table you could keept track of the last value seen and only show the popup if the current `id` value is different from the stored version.

An example of this would look something like:

```
public Class YourClass
{
    private int? lastId;
    private const string MESSAGE_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM send_eMessages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    private const string DATA_FILE_PATH = "somefilename.ext";

    private void AnteSala_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lastId = ReadLastSeenId();
         /*...Your Timer Code...*/
    }

    private void ReadInformationFromeMessage()
    {
        try
        {   
            var myCommand = new MySqlCommand(MESSAGE_QUERY, ConexaoBancoMySql.GetConexao());
            var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if(reader.Read())
            {
                int currentId = reader.GetInt32("id");

                if(currentId != this.lastId)
                {
                    this.lastId = currentId;
                    var eMessage = (reader.GetString("eMessage"));

                    /*...Your Popup Code...*/

                    WriteLastSeenId(this.lastId);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ConexaoBancoMySql.FecharConexao();
        }
    }

    private static void WriteLastSeenId(int? id)
    {
        string rawValue = (id != null ? id.Value.ToString() : string.Empty);

        File.WriteAllText(DATA_FILE_PATH, rawValue);
    }

    private static int? ReadLastSeenId()
    {
        int? id = null;

        if(File.Exists(DATA_FILE_PATH))
        {
            string rawValue = File.ReadAllText(DATA_FILE_PATH);

            if (int.TryParse(inputString, out int temp))
            {
                id = temp;
            }
        }

        return id;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this code so there may be errors but it should give you an idea of how you could go about this

Comment: I understand, but if this same application was closed and then opened, in theory the last **`id`** will be displayed again as false positive, do you agree? how we solved this, I thought maybe a .dat control

Comment: That's a different situation if you want to track that across application executions. Saving the last seen `id` to a file is a great and easy way to handle this. I've update the answer with a very basic example. You could store this information any way you want (XML, JSON, raw bytes, etc.). One thing to be aware of is that if this file gets deleted or moved you could get false positives. To solve _that_ issues you'd need to store something in the database

Comment: as soon as I get home I will post the solution, then give you feedback .... tks tks

Answer (score 0):

@amura.cxg, thank you, I made some adjustments and everything seems to work very well now, I leave here the code for those who need and look for a day.

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using eMessage.Classes;
using Tulpep.NotificationWindow;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace eMessage.Forms
{
    public partial class EMessageForm : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        private int? _lastId;
        private const string MessageQuery = "SELECT * FROM eMessage ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        private const string DataFilePath = "somefilename.ext";

/*
        private static string _eMessage1;
*/
        public EMessageForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void EMessageForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _lastId = ReadLastSeenId();

            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer
            {

                Interval = 100,
                SynchronizingObject = this,


            };
            timer.Elapsed += delegate
            {
                ReadInformationFromeMessage();
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
        private void ReadInformationFromeMessage()
        {
            try
            {
                var myCommand = new MySqlCommand(MessageQuery, ConexaoBancoMySql.GetConexao());
                var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (!reader.Read()) return;
                var currentId = reader.GetInt32("id");

                if (currentId == _lastId) return;
                _lastId = currentId;
                var eMessage = (reader.GetString("eMessage"));

                var pop = new PopupNotifier
                {
                    //escopo de mensagem
                    TitleText = "*  lastInfo  *",
                    ContentText = "" + eMessage,
                    //fim do escopo de mensagem
                    TitleFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12),
                    //cor do titulo do form
                    TitleColor = Color.White,
                    BodyColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 75, 0),
                    //contorno do form
                    BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0),
                    //cor da fonte do aviso
                    ContentColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255),
                    //tamanho da fonte
                    ContentFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12F),
                    //cor da fonte do aviso quando mouse em cima
                    ContentHoverColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255),
                    //centralizacao da mensagem no form 
                    ImagePadding = new Padding(0),
                    ContentPadding = new Padding(10),
                    Delay = 15000,
                    GradientPower = 150,
                    //tamanho da borda superior
                    HeaderHeight = 1,
                    Scroll = true,
                    ShowCloseButton = true,
                    ShowGrip = true,
                    ShowOptionsButton = false,

                };
                pop.Popup();

                WriteLastSeenId(_lastId);
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                ConexaoBancoMySql.FecharConexao();
            }
        }
        private static void WriteLastSeenId(int? id)
        {
            var rawValue = (id != null ? id.Value.ToString() : string.Empty);

            File.WriteAllText(DataFilePath, rawValue);
        }
        private static int? ReadLastSeenId()
        {
            int? id = null;

            if (!File.Exists(DataFilePath)) return null;
            var rawValue = File.ReadAllText(DataFilePath);

            if (int.TryParse(rawValue, out var temp))
            {
                id = temp;
            }

            return id;
        }
    }
}
```